# IAR <time.h>, localtime, mktime

Tags: c, iar, mktime, localtime, time.h

I am using the DLib for your IAR-Compiler and wanted to convert a UTC-timestamp to a local timestamp.

I am located in Germany hence my implementation for the __getzone-method is as followed:

```
char const * __getzone() {
  return ":GMT+1:GMT+2:0100:(1980)032502+0:102503+0";
}
```

I wrote some testcode:

```
time_t ts = 1509238797L;//29.10.2017-02:59:57 3 seconds before dst
struct tm* pre = localtime(&ts);

time_t after = ts + 5L;//wait 5 seconds -> 29.10.2017-02:00:02
struct tm* post = localtime(&after);
```

The "pre" variable is fine but the "post" variable contains the value:
29.10.2017-03:00:02 but it should be 29.10.2017-02:00:02.

I debugged the code in Visual-Studio and everything seems to work there. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your `__getzone()` should return: `return ":GMT+1:GMT+2:0100:(1980)032502+0:092503+0";` because the day light saving time ends in september not october 1980 in germany. Further this is a very nice explanation of the function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24640784/8051589. Day light saving time in germany: `Begin 1980 Sunday, 6. April 1980 2:00 CET | End: Sunday, 28. September 1980 3:00 CEST`.

Comment: Thats wrong. Dailight saving time ends on Oktober:
https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany/berlin?year=2017

Comment: In 1980 is `Sunday, 6 April, 02:00 Sunday, 28 September, 03:00`

Comment: Yes as I said... Your rule is for 1980 in `__getzone()` so you have to take the return value that I already mentioned. Then it should work. Please report.

Comment: @AndreKampling The 1980-Part is optional. You could remove the whole part and get: 
:GMT+1:GMT+2:0100:032502+0:102503+0

Daylight savin time in germany still ends on the last sunday in Oktober and not in September.

If it is possible for you to change your browser locale to German/Germany you can try this site: https://www.epochconverter.com/

Enter 1509238797 and 1509238802 the duration between those 2 is 5 seconds. The first will be 
"Sunday, 29.10 2017 02:59:57 GMT+02:00 DST"  and the other:
"Sunday, 29.10 2017 02:00:02 GMT+01:00"

Thats the result i would expect

Comment: Ok got that I agree to what you've said. How do you get to the Ascii date values could you add that code too? Or do you just look into the `struct tm`?

Comment: @AndreKampling i looked inside the variables via the debugger

Comment: I've upvote your answer also you can self accept your answer to mark it for the community.

Comment: The site is telling me, that i can accept my own answer in 2 days. I will do that then. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess i found it myself. The right String is:
:GMT+1:GMT+2:0100:032502+0:102502+0

DST starts at 2 o'clock and ends at 2 o'clock and not like i thought at 3 o'clock.
I guess the api description is not quite perfect.

Some Tests to verify the DST-Jumps:

```
//Forward
time_t ts = 1490489997L;//26.03.2017-01:59:57 3 seconds before dst
struct tm* pre = localtime(&ts);

time_t after = ts + 5L;//wait 5 seconds -> 26.03.2017-03:00:02
struct tm* post = localtime(&after);

//Backward
time_t ts = 1509238797L;//29.10.2017-02:59:57 3 seconds before dst
struct tm* pre = localtime(&ts);

time_t after = ts + 5L;//wait 5 seconds -> 29.10.2017-02:00:02
struct tm* post = localtime(&after);
```